# Error 1402 : Could not open Key

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I was installing KB2467175 Update that The following error has been occurred !

[image: Error 1402 : Could not open Key]

How can I fix it?

Comment: I've done the instructions of these links, but no progress : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302853 ; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236427 ; http://www.okino.com/conv/changing_windows_registry_permissions.htm